# Angular 6 - Not Include Shared Component in Build

Tags: angular

I have some common components build by Angular, and now I use those components build some views in difference app. When I build an app by cli, it will include the source of common components used in view, my question is: **Is it possible to put all common components in one places, and all apps build by those components not include those components in build bundle and can reference component in that places?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is one of the sole reasons angular has modules.

Create a shared module -- add all your components in that `shared.module.ts` file instead of `app.component.ts` and then add the components in exports array in NgModule decorator.

After that just import the module wherever you want.

You can also use lazy loading

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will take a look about the shared module things. I am not familiar with shared module things so I want to double confirm that when build the app by cli, the components in shared module will not include in app bundle, right?